# malloc succeed but assignment failed

Tags: c, malloc

We successfully allocated memory for x_space using malloc function. However it failed while assigning values to them. thanks for your attention.

The following is from train.c of Liblinear(an open source svm tool).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct feature_node
{
    int index;
    double value;
};

void main()
{
    struct feature_node * x_space;
    long j;

    x_space =(struct feature_node *)malloc(306396532*sizeof(struct feature_node));

    if(x_space)
    {
        for(j=0;j<306396532;j++)
            x_space[j].index=0;  /* fail when j=37961212, ACCESS VIOLATION */
    }
    else        
        printf("malloc failed.\n");

    puts("End");
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Hint: What does `306396500 * sizeof(double)` evaluate to? And how big is the `int` type?

Comment: How did you know `malloc` succeeded? you didn't check the return value of `malloc`

Comment: @YuHao If it failed, then chances are, it would've crashed on the very first iteration.

Comment: sizeof(double) is 8. 306396500 * sizeof(double)

Comment: before going into for loop. Can you add 

`if (p) { .. } else puts("malloc failed");`

Comment: why is that putchar('E') for ?

Comment: don't cast the return of malloc

Comment: voted to close. OP constantly changes the source code he's asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're on a machine with a processor that can't access a single memory segment of over 4GB (that's a 32 bit address space). Your compiler and/or library just aren't smart enough to fail when you allocate 4.5 GB (that's assuming 32-bit ints and 64-bit longs), so it fails later when you try to access it.

Instead of allocating an array of structures, try separate arrays for the int and double. That might just keep them under the limit.

Comment: Thanks. I ran it on Windows Xp (32bits) and Windows 2003 Server Enterprise(32bits). And we got the Access Violation error.

Comment: I tested this program on CentOS 64bit and succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrap-around, so you allocate much less than you think.

Assuming `double` must be aligned on 8 bytes, then `sizeof(struct feature_node)` is 16 (4 + 8 + 4 padding). On a 32bit machine, `306396532*sizeof(struct feature_node)` should be 4.8GB, but this wraps around to 0.8GB, which is what `malloc` gets, and what it allocates. Later, the loop tries to access beyond what was allocated, and fails.

Comment: I tested this program on CentOS 64bit and succeeded.

Comment: 4.9GB doesn't overflow in 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

This program shows you some information about the computer's memory,
so you can get information before allocate memory , i hope is for you useful :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>

#define DIV 1048576
#define WIDTH 7

void  main()
{
  MEMORYSTATUSEX statex;

  statex.dwLength = sizeof (statex);

  GlobalMemoryStatusEx (&statex);


   printf (TEXT("There is  %*ld percent of memory in use.\n"),WIDTH, statex.dwMemoryLoad);
   printf (TEXT("There are %*I64d total Mbytes of physical memory.\n"),WIDTH,statex.ullTotalPhys/DIV);
   printf (TEXT("There are %*I64d free Mbytes of physical memory.\n"),WIDTH, statex.ullAvailPhys/DIV);
   printf (TEXT("There are %*I64d total Mbytes of paging file.\n"),WIDTH, statex.ullTotalPageFile/DIV);
   printf (TEXT("There are %*I64d free Mbytes of paging file.\n"),WIDTH, statex.ullAvailPageFile/DIV);
   printf (TEXT("There are %*I64d total Mbytes of virtual memory.\n"),WIDTH, statex.ullTotalVirtual/DIV);
   printf (TEXT("There are %*I64d free Mbytes of virtual memory.\n"),WIDTH, statex.ullAvailVirtual/DIV);
   printf (TEXT("There are %*I64d free Mbytes of extended memory.\n"),WIDTH, statex.ullAvailExtendedVirtual/DIV);
}
```

compile with gcc x.c -o x -lpsapi